# Determine the vector equation of a line in R3, given by the Cartesian equations

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

The cartesian equation

$$\frac{x-1}{3}=y+2=\frac{5-z}{4}$$

The answer that was given which I couldn't get...

$$l:r\:=\:\begin{pmatrix}7\\ 0\\ -3\end{pmatrix}+s\begin{pmatrix}3\\ 1\\ -4\end{pmatrix},\:s\:∈\:R$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$t=\frac{x-1}{3}=y+2=\frac{5-z}{4}$$

Then $x=3t+1$, $y=t-2$, $z=5-4t$ and

$$r = \begin{pmatrix}1\\ -2\\ 5\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix}3\\ 1\\ -4\end{pmatrix},\:t\in \mathbb{R}$$

Let's take $t=s+2$, then

$$r = \begin{pmatrix}1\\ -2\\ 5\end{pmatrix}+2\begin{pmatrix}3\\ 1\\ -4\end{pmatrix}+s\begin{pmatrix}3\\ 1\\ -4\end{pmatrix},\:s\in \mathbb{R}$$

$$r = \begin{pmatrix}7\\ 0\\ -3\end{pmatrix}+s\begin{pmatrix}3\\ 1\\ -4\end{pmatrix},\:s\in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It will be helpful if you can explain why is there a need for t = s + 2?

Comment: Answer using $t$ is also correct for this problem. The only need for $t=s+2$ is to show that answer can be written in the same form as in your question.

Comment: There are lots of correct forms of the answer. You could simply say $x=t$ then get $y$ and $z$ in terms of t. The form of possible answer will differ in the point they go through and the multiple of the direction $(3, 1, -4)$.